# How to achieve python-like behavior with references in c++?

Tags: python, c++, reference

In python, if I do:

```
a = []
b = a 
a.append(1)
b[0] == 1
```

This works fine, as both a and b are pointing to the underlying object on the heap.

What would be the equivalent C++ code?

Comment: Make `b` a reference to whatever `a` is.

Answer (score 5):

> What would be the equivalent C++ code?

Following would be a decent translation:

```
std::vector<int> a;
auto& b = a;
a.push_back(1);
b[0] == 1;
```

The key to having reference semantics is to use a reference variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared_ptr: all copies are operate single instance of data. And you will be able to reassign new instance for operations (it's better than reference).

Comment: Could you argument why it would be better than references? I'd say if you can, then always use a reference. It does not have the (minimal) overhead of a shared_ptr and is easier to use. That said, references of course have limitations and sometimes you are forced to use pointers.

Comment: I think you're closer to what the op wants. a shared pointer will act closer to how a reference works in other languages than a c++ reference type.

Comment: @AlexGeorg IMO this answer is close to what OP wants to achieve. His experience in Python is due to the fact that Python's vars are underhood shared pointers

Comment: @mvidelgauz True, but does it really make sense to teach someone the suboptimal solution? Not to mention that especially with vectors, pointers are looking nasty in C++ because he gotta access the values like `(*b)[0] == 1` if b is a pointer.

Comment: @AlexGeorg I understand your point and it does make sense to me. But I suspect that OP gave just a minimal example in their question. The real spirit of the question is _how to achieve equal behavior of vars_ in a potentially large and more complex software (including passing them between objects, storing in containers, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

While the reference should be preferred when possible due to their simplicity, just to be complete, here a solution with shared pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
 auto a = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();
 auto b = a;
 a->push_back(1);

 std::cout << "This is One: " << (*b)[0] << "\n";
}
```

Yeah, c++ can look really bad compared to python for trivial things...
At least we have "auto" now to avoid repeatedly having to type: `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>` in this case.